# How to check is object is instance of datetime.time

Tags: python, datetime

```
from datetime import datetime as datetime
print(type(datetime.now().time())) #outputs <class 'datetime.time'>
print(type(datetime.time))         #outputs <class 'method_descriptor'>
```

I think this code abstract says it all.
Why is the type operator returning something that is not a type ?

Especially I do not understand why I get a different result if I do:

```
print(type(type(datetime.now().time()))) #returns type
```

and

```
isinstance(datetime.now().time(), datetime.time)
```

TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types

What can I do if I want to test if an object is of the same type of what is returned by .time() method from datetime

Comment: `type(object) == datetime.time`

Comment: Please don't say things like "the abstract says it all"; it really doesn't, your question is quite hard to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confused because there are two things here called `datetime`; the module, and the class within that module. You've imported the class only, not the parent module.

The `datetime.datetime` class defines an instance method `time()` which converts the object into an instance of class `datetime.time`.

Things would be clearer if you imported the module rather than the class:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> print(type(datetime.datetime.now().time()))
<class 'datetime.time'>
>>> print(type(datetime.time))
<class 'type'>
```

(Note also though that from your mention of `method_descriptor` you must be using Python 2.7, which is very old. Please upgrade to Python 3, where the result of `type(datetime.datetime.now().time)` gives `builtin_function_or_method`.)